# Opening firefox browser in ios Simulator using Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I would like to open the firefox browser on the iphone (5, 6 or 6 plus) **simulator** using Appium. I tired by giving the absolute app path (of firefox browser app in the mac machind) in appium ios settings itself but it did not work. I've read about installing Firefox OS Simulator. Can I open the firefox browser in IOS Simulator or android simulator as an app or do I have to use Firefox's simulator? Please advice with detailed steps.
Thanks in advance!!
PS: I am using the latest versions of appium and ios

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) android simulator and appium.
In order to install firefox you just take the apk [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases/latest-beta/android-x86/multi/)
The details steps:

1. Install Android SDK.
2. Start the emulator by going to $SDK_root/emulator.exe.
3. Go to command prompt and go to the directory $SDK_root/platform-tools (or else add the path to windows environment)
4. Type in the command adb install.

Please note that the simulator testing usually not enough and you have test your app also on the real device.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I have connected samsung galaxy s4 to my mac machine and have tried running my code. Firefox app opens but when I give 'driver.get("some url)' appium fails with the following message.'WebDriver expection: Not yet implemented'. I realised that its because the context of Firefox is 'NATIVE_APP' only. However, we can give URL's only for 'WEBVIEW_1' Can you suggest any workaround for me to enter a URL is Firefox app on android device?

Comment: Following [this](https://discuss.appium.io/t/firefox-on-android/2492) appium is not supporting firefox for Android now.